# How can I find out what causes undefined behaviour in my program?

Tags: c++, qt, undefined-behavior

My Qt application consists of four screens that can be switched. These screens are added to a QStackedLayout Class with addWidget(). The switching between screens happens with setCurrentWidget().

Adding some variables in the header file in one of the screens(/classes) always causes the program to crash. Debugging gives me a segfault at adwidget() where I try to add that screen to the Layout.

Now if I clean all before the build it always works. Also if just change something in the header file of some other class (can be any header file) and I rebuild only that one header file it works aswell.

It only happens with that one screen(/class). It doesn't matter what type of variable I add. Doesn't matter if they are public or private. The class is almost identical with others that work without any problem. When I compile I get no warnings or errors. It just crashes at addwidget().

Is there any way to find out whats going on?

**edit:**
This is the result of valgrind memcheck:
[image]

Line 18 in compassdebugscreen.cpp is: QString const strCalib3DStartBtn = "Start Calib 3D";

Line 14 in main.cpp is: QApplication a(argc, argv)

Comment: Do you have the Q_OBJECT macro in your class declaration? Does the moc tool run on the file every time you modify it?

Comment: Use `valgrind`.

Comment: @Steve: Yes I do. When I hit run a new moc_***.o file is created.

Comment: @Velkan: I added a screeshot of the results above. Don't really know what it means though.

Comment: There are probably some class members of simple types like `int` or `char*` that aren't initialized in the constructor of the class. Maybe some important logic uses them before they are set.

Comment: UBSan (gcc >4.9 or clang) can help a lot with finding those at run time as well.

Comment: Line 18 in compassdebugscreen.cpp is: QString const strCalib3DStartBtn = "Start Calib 3D";
Line 14 in main.cpp is: QApplication a(argc, argv);
Anything wrong with these?

Comment: Did you delete the build folder and built the project again? Sometimes you can make your project internally binary-incompatible without the build system noticing.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you! Seems like that worked. At least I can't reproduce the undefined behaviour now by adding more variables. 

Can you give further information on what happened here? (Pointers or keywords to google are appreciated aswell)

Comment: All the parts of your program have to be binary-compatible. What happened was this: you've changed a header, and other translation units that used that header - perhaps indirectly - weren't recompiled because the build system had an outdated representation of the dependencies in your project. So now those other stale object files are binary incompatible with the changes you've done to the header and to its implementation, and boom it crashes. Common thing. When you add files **or** add dependencies, delete the build folder. Even re-running qmake is not enough sometimes.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).